# Google calendar api ACL with service account

Tags: google-calendar-api, acl, service-accounts

I have a requirement to read the ACL list for all (rooms') calendars across the domain. It appears like only a user of a calendar with "Owner" (Make changes and manage sharing) role can read its ACL list. But the google admin console is not letting me assign an "Owner" role to a service account. My requirement is to be able to read ACL list of all rooms across the domain on a schedule. Is there any other way I can do this? See the image for reference:

[Cannot assign owner role to service account but able to assign it for a test user account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRR1h.png)

I am getting a 403 forbidden error when I tried the ACL List API with the highest possible role I can assign to the service account

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue. I'm using domain-wide delegation to an admin-level account and still getting 403.